Itô's lemma on a manifold
Let $X_t$ be a process on $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that
$$
dX_t = a(w, t)dt + b(w, t)dB_t,
$$
where $a(w, t)$ and $b(w, t)$ are adapted, measurable and integrable processes in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $\mathbb{R}$, respectively. Furthermore, $B_t$ is a brownian motion on $\mathbb{R}^d$.
It is known that for every $f \in C^{2}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, the process $Y_t := f(X_t)$ verifies
$$
dY_t = \left(\langle a(w, t), \nabla f(X_t)\rangle + \frac{1}{2}b(w, t)^2 \Delta f(X_t)\right)dt + b(w, t) \langle \nabla f(X_t), dB_t\rangle, \quad (1)
$$
where $\nabla f$ is the gradient of $f$, $\Delta f$ is the Laplacian of $f$ and $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ denotes the Euclidean inner product.
The above result it known as Itô's Lemma.
It now feels natural to extend the above result for Riemannian manifolds, in a suitable way:

$X_t$ is a process on $M$

$a(w, t)$ is now an adapted, measurable and integrable process in $TM$, the tangent bundle of $M$.

$\nabla f$ the gradient of $f$ in the Riemannian sense.

$\Delta$ is the Laplace-Beltrami operator.

$\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is given by the Riemannian metric $g_M$ of $M$.


I am aware of the existence of books such as Hsu's Stochastic Analysis on Manifolds, or Emery's Stochastic Calculus in Manifolds, but I have not been able to find a version of Itô's Lemma for Manifolds in a way which does not rely on taking charts or coordinates.
Again, I would like to see that Equation (1) holds when working on a Riemannian manifold. Is it explicitly written somewhere? Or does the above follow by any proposition written in the aforementioned books?
Edit: I have seen in Bruce K. Driver's "A primer on Riemannian geometry and stochastic analysis on path spaces", section 4, that embedding $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^k$ for some $k$, $X_t$ can be seen as a process on $\mathbb{R}^k$ such that $X_t(\omega) \in M$ for any $\omega \in \Omega$ and any $t \geq 0$. Furthermore, seeing $f$ as a function on $\mathbb{R}^k$, maybe $(1)$ holds trivially in the case of Riemannian manifolds just from seeing it on $\mathbb{R}^k$ for some $k$?

How do you want to write $dt$ or $dx$ without using the coordinates $t$ and $x,?$ Adding Brownian motion won't work any wonders.

@KurtG. Using the coordinate $t$ is fine. I don't see where the exact choice of coordinates plays a role in Equation (1), it looks coordinate-independent to me...

It looks like John Armstrong arxiv.org/abs/1602.03931 is an expert on this. Have fun diving into it.
